# BLE `onCharacteristicRead` not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

nowadays, I develop App with android BLE. 
but I have a problem..

here is code....

```
// Device connect call back
private final BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        // this will get called anytime you perform a read or write characteristic operation
                peripheralTextView.append("device read or wrote to\n");
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE,characteristic);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
        // this will get called when a device connects or disconnects
        System.out.println(newState);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        peripheralTextView.append("device disconnected\n");
                        connectToDevice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        disconnectDevice.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        peripheralTextView.append("device connected\n");
                        connectToDevice.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        disconnectDevice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                // discover services and characteristics for this device
                bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();

                break;
            default:
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        peripheralTextView.append("we encounterned an unknown state, uh oh\n");
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) {
        // this will get called after the client initiates a            BluetoothGatt.discoverServices() call
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                peripheralTextView.append("device services have been discovered\n");
            }
        });
        displayGattServices(bluetoothGatt.getServices());
    }

    @Override
    // Result of a characteristic read operation
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }
};

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
    final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for (byte byteChar : data)
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

..........\

```
public void disconnectDeviceSelected() {
    peripheralTextView.append("Disconnecting from device\n");
    bluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    if (gattServices == null) return;

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {

        final String uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
        System.out.println("Service discovered: " + uuid);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                peripheralTextView.append("Service disovered: "+uuid+"\n");
            }
        });
        new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                gattService.getCharacteristics();

        // Loops through available Characteristics.
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                gattCharacteristics) {

            final String charUuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
            System.out.println("Characteristic discovered for service: " + charUuid);
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    peripheralTextView.append("Characteristic discovered for service: "+charUuid+"\n");
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

and I run this code ...

scanning and connectting is done ;
 but onCharacteristicRead doesn't work ;( 
 I need your help plz!

Comment: are you sent any command to BLE device in order to receive response?

Comment: @HiteshGehlot Yes, I checked peripheral device send a data...;(

Comment: I don't see you call "readCharacteristic" anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

call this method in onServicesDiscovered and if this method return true then send command to ble device

```
public Boolean enableTXNotification() {
        /*
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            showMessage("mBluetoothGatt null" + mBluetoothGatt);
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return;
        }
            */
        BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(Lock.RX_SERVICE_UUID);
        if (RxService == null) {
            showMessage("Rx service not found!");
            broadcastUpdate(Lock.DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return false;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic TxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(Lock.TX_CHAR_UUID);
        if (TxChar == null) {
            showMessage("Tx charateristic not found!");
            broadcastUpdate(Lock.DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return false;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar, true);

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(Lock.CCCD);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        return true;
    }
```

let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: hi. I got Rx service not found!. Can u help?